# Reduce values when clustering to a distinct list of comma separated values (Mapbox Map SDK v10.13.0)

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have a GeoJsonSource where clustering is enabled. The feature collection provided to the source contains a property that I want to collect into a distinct list upon clustering.

The data I am trying to reduce can be stored as a string, so a comma separated string list is all I require for this (no arrays required which I know is not possible via clusterProperty/Properties).

The following code produces an empty string as the property for "cgis", I'm expecting to see a comma separated list of all the cgi values from the features which make up the cluster.

```kotlin
clusterProperties(
        hashMapOf(
            CGIS to concat {
                accumulated()
                Expression.switchCase {
                    inExpression {
                        get("cgi")
                        accumulated()
                    }
                    literal("")

                    eq {
                        accumulated()
                        literal("")
                    }
                    get("cgi")

                    concat {
                        literal(",")
                        get("cgi")
                    }
                }
            },
            ... other properties that have already been clustered via, max, sum, etc.
        )
    )
```

Any help is appreciated as the documentation around this is incredibly sparse.